# stuck at "Initializing internal preferences…"

Tags: linux, installation

When I run `Mathematica` for the first time, it get stuck at the splash screen saying "Initializing internal preferences…" It's doing something, as my CPU for that process is 100%. What's it doing? Will it stop, or is it in an ∞ loop?

I also get this output on the command line:

```
LinkConnect::linkc: -- Message text not found -- (LinkObject[f7bhq_shm, 3, 1])
```

Is this due Mathematica not having access to the network?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue?